# FCPX is getting stuck all the time

Tags: editing, final-cut-pro-x

I have a MBP 13” with a 1.4 GHz quad core i5 prosesor and 16 GB of ram.
All the footage Including the project is on a external usb stick with usb 3.

When I am editing a simple video clip, not in 4K, fcpx is getting stuck a lot. Mostly when I want to move a video a second back or forth or when I want to watch right after moving a video.

Does anybody have a idea what this could be?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performance, I would not use a USB stick, and as far as I know, this isn’t supported as well. I would recommend an external hard drive or for best performance the internal SSD.

If you still have problems, you should reset the FCPX settings. To do so quit FCPX then find the FCPX program icon in the application folder and hold down the command and option key and start FCPX. A dialogue will come up asking if you want to reset the configuration.

You can find more issue resolving in this article. 
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203477

Comment: Ah ok, I have also a externer hard drive, but I don’t know if it is a SSD. would you recommend a external harddrive over de usb

Comment: I checked again, it’s a HDD

Comment: Also, I have only 256 storage on my mac

Comment: Any external hard drive is supported and should work much better. If you have to work on external drives try use SSD with fastest Port your Mac has (thunderbolt, USB-C) if possible.

Comment: Good idea also to create Proxies for the footage.

Comment: And if you need even more help with performance use this workflow to create HEVC Proxies. https://www.rippletraining.com/blog/final-cut-pro-x/hevc-proxy-editing-in-final-cut-pro-x/

Comment: Ah, ok thx. Does the article you posted also cover proxies in general?

Comment: Yes, it does in short terms. If you need information about Proxies you can find more in the FCPX help.

Comment: ok, great thx!!

Answer (score 1):

Your bottleneck is the USB stick and USB 3.0 itself. There's simply not enough bandwidth to get smooth playback.

From your specs (quad i5, 1.4 GHz) I'm guessing you've got a the 2019 13" MBPro which should be powerful enough to handle quite some video editing, so I'd highly recommend getting an external SSD connected via Thunderbolt 3, or at least USB-C. While USB-C is optically the same plug as Thunderbolt 3, the protocol and speeds are different. Thunderbolt 3's max throughput is about 4x of what USB-C can handle.

For maximum performance get a NVMe SSD (M.2) drive and a Thunderbolt 3 enclosure. You can get 1TB with case for ca. 250 USD and the maximum throughput is just as fast as the internal drive (same technology), up to 1400 MB/s which should be enough to even edit 4k footage.